# Why aren't users images from camera showing up?

Tags: android

I am trying to allow users to select an image from camera and gallery and update an image view with the selected image. I am successful  in doing so if a user selects a picture from their gallery, however if they choose to take a picture with their camera I keep getting a null value. I am unsure as to why, I have all the necessary permission in my manifest file such as write and from read external storage.

```
//Creates popup and allows user to select book image from gallery or camera.
public void selectImageMenu(final View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gallery_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.openCamera:
                    openCamera();
                    return true;

                case R.id.openGallery:
                    openGallery();
                    return true;

                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}


//checks permission and if it's granted allows user the choice of choosing an image from gallery or camera
public void uploadImagePost(View view) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    } else {
        selectImageMenu(view);

    }

}

//opens camera to allow user to take a picture.
public void openCamera() {
    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replaced with any action code
}

//opens gallery to allow user to choose a book image
public void openGallery() {
    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);//one can be replaced with any action code

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                Glide
                    .with(CreatePostActivity.this)
                    .load(selectedImageUri)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.bookshelf)
                    .into(bookImage);
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                Glide
                    .with(CreatePostActivity.this)
                    .load(selectedImageUri)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.bookshelf)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(bookImage);

                break;
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your code

```
case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
                   bitmap = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
                   bookImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
```

there is another approach which is, store image into external file directory before you load image.
check this

```
btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    File pictureFile = null;
    pictureFile = getPictureFile();
    if (pictureFile != null) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
                        "com.xyx.yourproject",pictureFile);
                                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUESTCODE);
                            }
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });
```

to save to location and fetch the path of the image

```
private File getPictureFile() {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
        String pictureFile = "pic_" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = null;
        try {
            image = File.createTempFile(pictureFile,  ".jpg", storageDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity,
                    "Photo file can't be created, please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        pictureFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

and at last, in onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUESTCODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            File imgFile = new  File(pictureFilePath);

            /** use imgFile to print into your image view---code to print the image*/

        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


          /**-------your code*/


        }
    }
```

and for getting permission to access a local file storage directory, in your manifest file add these

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.xyz.yourpath"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths" />
        </provider>
```

you have to create a resource file 'paths' specifying your external-path in res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="yourfiles"
    path="Android/data/com.xyz.yourpackagename/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

now the images will be stored to an external path so you can use the file path to print the image into the image view

Comment: This is just thumbnail, not full image.

Comment: then you may have to store the image into local storage directory before loading to imageview

Answer (score 0):

To get proper image from camera you have to provide File that camera app can write to:

```
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

And then on activity result with REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO just read file that you created with `createImageFile` or thumbnail Bitmap object that will be in returned as extras 'data' field

You can find all answers here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java